# Property 'App' does not exist on type 'typeof Realm'.ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, realm

I am getting the following error message:

```
Property 'App' does not exist on type 'typeof Realm'.ts(2339)
```

This is the TypeScript that I using:

```
const getRealmApp: React.FC = () => {
  const appId = "<enter your Realm app ID here>"; // Set Realm app ID here.
  const appConfig = {
    id: appId,
    timeout: 10000,
  };

  return new Realm.App(appConfig);
};
```

Here are my imports:

```
import * as Realm from "realm";
```

Comment: Does the code work at runtime?

Comment: Yes, with @ts-ignore. But have another method?

Comment: Just wanted to verify that. I wouldn't recommend ignoring this error but it seems like the declarations you're using are missing information. They should be fixed but you can use module augmentation as a workaround

Comment: I'll try this... Thanks!